# Centering popup window in android does not work on all phones

Tags: android, android-layout, popup

On my app, I have different popup windows. On my phones and on all my virtual devices they are centered perfectly on the screen. Unfortunately that is not the case on all phones.

The code in my java file is the following:

EDIT: I have removed `fitSystemWindows=true`, but that does not help. My guess is that in `setStationPopup.showAtLocation(findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);` `Gravity.CENTER` does not behave as expected.

```
View stationPopView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popupsetstartpos, null);
setStationPopup = new PopupWindow(stationPopView);
setStationPopup.setWidth(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
setStationPopup.setHeight(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
setStationPopup.showAtLocation(findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
setStationPopup.update();
```

The `layout.xml` where the popup window is looks like

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@drawable/livebackground"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    tools:openDrawer="start">
    <!--tools:context="com.example.erikbylow.skeet25private.LiveSession"-->


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <!--<Spinner
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/add_spinner_disciplines"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            ></Spinner>-->

        <FrameLayout
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:id="@+id/live_session_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.65"></FrameLayout>


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/live_button_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.25">

        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <!--ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        ></ListView-->

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:clipToPadding="false"

        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The `layout.xml` for the popup window is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:id="@+id/popupwindow">

    <TextView
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="410dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:text="Set your start position"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/station_button_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/station_button_height"
            android:text="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="station1"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/station_button_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/station_button_height"
            android:text="2"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="station2"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/station_button_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/station_button_height"
            android:text="3"
            android:onClick="station3"
            android:clickable="true"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="@dimen/station_button_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/station_button_height"
            android:text="4"
            android:onClick="station4"
            android:clickable="true"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="@dimen/station_button_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/station_button_height"
            android:text="5"
            android:onClick="station5"
            android:clickable="true"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is that the popup window is not centered on some phones. For example on my cousin's `Xperia Z5` and `Android version 7.0` it looks like:
[image]

On all my virtual devices with different screen sizes and resolutions and both my test phones, `Xperia Z5` and `Nexus 5` it looks like

[image]

I really do not understand this behaviour.`GRAVITY.Center` would work on all devices. Also the `drawer_layout` is set to `match_parent` in size so I would expect them to fill the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing :

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

or use `android:fitsSystemWindows="false"`

in your `layout.xml` in `DrawerLayout` and also from other layout.

**fitsSystemWindows**

> System windows are the parts of the screen where the system is drawing
>   either non-interactive (in the case of the status bar) or interactive
>   (in the case of the navigation bar) content.Most of the time, your app
>   won’t need to draw under the status bar or the navigation bar, but if
>   you do: you need to make sure interactive elements (like buttons)
>   aren’t hidden underneath them. That’s what the default behavior of the
>   `android:fitsSystemWindows=“true”` attribute gives you: it sets the
>   padding of the View to ensure the contents don’t overlay the system
>   windows.

Comment: Thx, I will give that a try.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not seem to work. Still placed on top of the screen on my cousin's Z5

Comment: you have added `fitsystemWindows` 4 times in your layout...you need to remove all of them..